# How to troubleshoot long builds in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, build

Is it possible in any way to troubleshoot the build process in Visual Studio? I'd like to see which part of the build specifically takes so much time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tools\Options\Project and Solutions\Build and Run\MSBuild output verbosity -> verbose.

In the Output Window, you'll get a time summary at the end, and you can see at which point in the process there is a long pause.

Comment: Ok, so now I've information that target CoreCompile inside one of the projects takes 200202 miliseconds.. can I go deeper and check why?

Comment: CoreCompile typically is just running the command-line compiler on the source code (the command-line should show in the output window).  At that point, you might need to ask a more specific question about that compiler (which compiler is it?).

Answer (score 0):

Watch the output window in visual studio during a build or build from the command line directly with MSBuild. You should be able to notice where the build process is spending most of its time.